# how do i replace some tags and their content with custom text in php?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

i have a string and im using `preg_match_all` to find some tags in that string:

```
$str = " 
Line 1: This is a string 
Line 2: [img]http://placehold.it/350x150[/img] Should not be [youtube]SDeWJqKx3Y0[/youtube] included."; 

preg_match_all("~\[img](.+?)\[/img]~i", $str, $img);  
preg_match_all("~\[youtube](.+?)\[/youtube]~i", $str, $youtube);

foreach ($img[1] as $key => $value) {
    echo '<img src="'.$value.'" "/>';
}

foreach ($youtube[1] as $key => $value) {
    echo '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$value.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>';
}
```

this will return exactly what is being echoes with the right values.

but what i actually want is to return the entire string with the the `[img]` and `[youtube]` tags replaced with the values from those foreach statements:

```
Line 1: This is a string 
    Line 2: <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" "/> Should not be <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SDeWJqKx3Y0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe> included.
```

i'm not looking for a 3rd party alternative, just plain php functions.

i'm thinking of using `preg_match` and some `case` and `switch` statements, but i didn't succeeded yet

an ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

With something like this.

```
$pattern = Array();
$pattern[0] = "~\[img](.+?)\[/img]~i";
$pattern[1] = "~\[youtube](.+?)\[/youtube]~i";

$replacement = Array();
$replacement[0] = '<img src="${1}" "/>';
$replacement[1] =  '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/${1}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>';

$stringToReturn = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

Comment: looks like this did it. I've tried the same thing earlier and i got a bunch of errors by using `http://writecodeonline.com/php/`. Looks like it can't do that